# Can I use "map" as a substitute for "for each"/"for in"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

For a little while now [javascript has the "map" function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Map) to loop over arrays.

It appears possible to use it as a 'foreach' operator for example:

```
fruitbowl.map(function(fruit){ 
                  ... do stuff with fruit
              })
```

Is this better or worse than saying

```
for(var i in fruitbowl){ 
     ... do stuff with fruitbowl[i] 
}
```

Saves having to use the index but adds a callback; it doesn't seem very common so I hesitate to use it but still want to.

Comment: I wonder what browser support is like?

Comment: Browser support is the question. "Map" needs 1.5, "forEach" needs 1.6.  I'm seeing a rule-of-thumb forming: Map when assigning, forEach when processing, and for-in when legacy.

Comment: For browser support, give a look to this: [ES5 Compatibility Table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table).

Comment: oh, ffs, not supported by msie. That's why it's so uncommon. But the routines provided in the reference at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) save the day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The three methods you mention have different purposes.

The purpose of the `Array.prototype.map` method is to create a *new array* with the results of calling the callback function on every array element.

The purpose of the `Array.prototype.forEach` method is to iterate over an array, executing the provided callback function once per array element.

The purpose of the `for...in` statement is to *enumerate object properties*.

I think that the `for...in` statement should be avoided to traverse any array-like<sup>1</sup> object, where the real purpose is **iterate** over numeric indexes and not **enumerate** the object properties (even knowing that those indexes are properties).

Reasons to avoid `for...in` to iterate array-like objects:

- Iterates over *inherited user-defined properties* in addition to the array elements, if you use a library like MooTools for example, which extend the `Array.prototype` object, you will see all those extended properties.
- The order of iteration is arbitrary, the elements may not be visited in numeric order.

Give a look to this article:

- [Iteration VS Enumeration](http://www.dhtmlkitchen.com/?category=/JavaScript/&date=2007/10/21/&entry=Iteration-Enumeration-Primitives-and-Objects)

---

<sub>1</sub> By array-like objects I mean any object that contains sequential numeric properties, and a `length` property

Answer (score 3):

*That* use is considered valid, but it's bad style to use a map operation strictly for its side effects instead.

Answer (score 1):

Readability is worth a lot.  The map might be confusing to those who've never seen it used this way.  It violates the "principle of least surprise."

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, map is used similarly but more naturally.

My rule of thumb is if it does not read better than a loop then don't use it. Difficult to debug. But for [certain functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), map is more natural than a loop. If you need to scratch your head over it -- don't do it. Pity the guy who follows you, including yourself sometime from now!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `map` for its side effects. If your task is iterating over an array to do something with each object, use `foreach`.  If you are mapping values, e.g. escaping an array of strings, use `map`. There's nothing like clarity and programmer intent over being clever.